# Man in space who can telepathically communicate with his unborn daughter

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, telepathy

This was a sci-fi book. In it, there was a man that was in space, very far from his family (I think that his family are on Earth but I'm not sure). The man can telepathically communicate with his daughter. She and her twin haven't been born yet; they're fetuses, but she can communicate telepathically with her father.

Comment: Hello, Jose! For some help making this question better so you're more likely to get an answer, see [this handy guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999)! Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of ["Psyclops"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41216) by Brian Aldiss, which was the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145638/trying-to-find-a-story-about-an-unborn-telepathic-baby-who-can-save-a-spaceship) ***but***: it was a short story not a novel; the unborn telepath is a boy child; the mother & unborn child are on a spaceship headed for Earth; the father is dying on an alien planet. The story is narrated by the unborn child. You can read the whole story [here](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_049v17_1956-07#page/n31/mode/2up)

Comment: In Aldiss's story, the boy does have a twin sister, but only the boy is a telepath.

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @user14111 want to put it as an answer? I would vote to close as dupe as the one you provided is accepted, but I'm a bit taken aback - there's a comment by OP saying it's not the one. :/ (Well, actually it's unclear what they seemed to think...)

Comment: @Jenayah Did you read the OP's [last comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145638/trying-to-find-a-story-about-an-unborn-telepathic-baby-who-can-save-a-spaceship/145642#comment372232_145642)? After some initial doubts, tula accepted the answer. Accepted is accepted.

Comment: @user14111 yeah, hence my "it's unclear what they seemed to think" sentence. Anyway yep, it's got a checkmark, dupe-target. (And good answer, by the way)

Comment: @Jenayah Thank you. I was satisfied with my previous answer, and had no interest in posting another answer for the same story.